# Check if URL has content in PHP

Tags: php, html, url

I've a PHP file. In this file I need to check, if my URL has the following ending:

```
www.example.de/dashboard/2/
```

So the ending can be a number `1 - 99+` which is always at the end of the url between two slashes. I can't use `$_GET` here. If it is `$_GET`, it would be easy:

```
if ( isset($_GET['ending']) ) :
```

So how can I do this without a parameter in the URL? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`explode`](https://www.php.net/explode):

```
$url = 'http://www.example.de/dashboard/2/';

$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH); // '/dashboard/2/'
$parts = explode('/', $path);          // ['', 'dashboard', '2', '']
$section = $parts[1];                  // 'dashboard'
$ending = $parts[2];                   // '2'
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/dv6Cn**

You can also make use of [URL rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained) (this is for a Apache-based web server, but you can find simular resources for nginx or any other web servers if need be).

Comment: I'll take this one here because it's simple and it works :)

Answer (score 2):

```php
if(preg_match('^\/dashboard\/(\d+)', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
    foo();
}
```

Use regular expression on the request uri

Comment: I have a problem and try to solve it with RegExp. Now i had two problems :) For this case explode is best way.

Comment: Thanks for spending time and trying to help me!

Answer (score 1):

A more dynamic way is to explode and use array_filter to remove empty values then pick the last item.
If the item * 1 is the same as the item then we know it's a number.
(The return from explode is strings so we cant use is_int)

```
$url = "http://www.example.de/dashboard/2/";
$parts = array_filter(explode("/", $url));
$ending = end($parts);
if($ending*1 == $ending) echo $ending; //2
```

Comment: Multiplying a string will yield a warning.

Comment: Now try with an URL that doesn't end with a "number". PHP somehow manages to do it with strings such as "2" because it's an awful language, but still :)

Comment: Thanks for spending time and trying to help me!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to target this url to script - in web server config. For nginx and index.php:

```
try_files $uri @rewrite_location;
location @rewrite_location {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?link=$1&$args last;
}
```

Second - you need to parse URI. In $end you find what you want

```
$link_as_array = array_values(array_diff(explode("/", $url), array('')));
$max = count($link_as_array) - 1;
$end = $link_as_array[$max];
```

Comment: No problem, but you know you can try your code before posting? https://3v4l.org/uEnLp

Comment: Thanks for spending time and trying to help me!

Comment: Oh, need to go asleep, forget about last slash. But this code is not fine at all, this is mock, not production ready.

Answer (score 0):

I would think this way. If the URL is always the same, or the same format, I'll do the following:

1. Check for the approx URL.
2. Split the URL into pieces.
3. Find if there's the part I am looking for.
4. Extract the number.

```php
<?php
  $url = "http://www.example.de/dashboard/2/";
  if (strpos($url, "www.example.de/dashboard") === 7 or strpos($url, "www.example.de/dashboard") === 8) {
    $urlParts = explode("/", $url);
    if (isset($urlParts[4]) && isNumeric($urlParts[4]))
      echo "Yes! It is {$urlParts[4]}.";
  }
?>
```

The `strpos` with `7` and `8` is for URL with `http://` or `https://`.

The above will give you the output as the numeric part if it is set. I hope this works out.

Comment: I think your `explode` is missing an argument :)

Comment: @Jeto Thanks a lot. I have corrected the errors. There were two. ‍♂️

Comment: Why not doing $urlParts[-1] ?

Comment: @MsuArven Not valid in PHP (unless you explicitly have a `-1` index in your array).

Comment: @MsuArven Reason being if you have a URL with more params, say `dashboard/2/hello/world`, your option will not work. I am trying to get the next directory after `dashboard`.

Comment: @Jeto Uh ? I'm doing it, it's 100% valid.

Comment: @MsuArven & Praveen [No it doesn't?](https://3v4l.org/iI7jc) It only works with strings.

Comment: `dashboard/2/hello/world` is not what OP request in question. It's the ending that needs to be captured

Comment: @MsuArven Yep, it doesn't work. https://eval.in/1087330 & https://eval.in/1087329

Comment: @Andreas Another way of thinking in the future, what if the URL gets new stuff added?

Comment: In that case, another way of thinking. What if a new folder is created above?

Comment: @Andreas No comments. 

Comment: Thanks for spending time and trying to help me!